# Using setpgid in a mini-shell breaks interactive commands

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, posix

I'm trying to write a mini-shell in C using [this template](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/ics3/code/ecf/shellex.c). But whenever I try to use interactive commands such as `less` and `vi`, the shell gets stuck on waitpid (with `WUNTRACED` enabled these commands return immediately because they are stopped by a job control signal as indicated by `ps`) . Other commands that don't require input such as `ls` are fine. The root cause is `setpgid`, which seems to puts the forked child process (such as `less` and `vi`) into a different process group which no longer shares a terminal. The child process is therefore stopped by a job control signal. Deleting `setpgid` will make the mini-shell work again, but it can't be removed since the mini-shell needs to control its foreground processes as a group (e.g. if the foreground process P forks additional processes P1 and P2, the shell, upon receiving a `SIGTSTP` from the user, should stop P, P1, and P2. This can be conveniently done if P, P1, P2 are in the same process group whose pgid is the same as P's pid. We can just send SIGTSTP to the entire process group).

I have tried to use `tcsetpgrp` to fix my shell. Although it'll make commands such as `vi` functional again, the mini-shell will automatically exit upon completion of the forked child, presumably because the parent shell mistakenly views the completion of the forked child as also the completion of the mini-shell.

Is there a fix which will still allow me to keep setpgid?

```
// full code is in the provided link
if (!builtin_command(argv)) {
    if ((pid = Fork()) == 0) {   /* Child runs user job */
        if (execve(argv[0], argv, environ) < 0) {
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            printf("%s: Command not found.\n", argv[0]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    // call wrapper function for error handling
    // set process group id of child to the pid of child
    Setpgid(pid, 0);
    if (!bg) {
        // foreground process, should wait for completion
        // tcsetpgrp does make vi and less work, 
        // but their completion also terminates the mini-shell
        // tcsetpgrp(STDERR_FILENO, pid);
        int status;
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0) {
            unix_error("waitfg: waitpid error");
        }
    } else {
        // background process
        printf("%d %s", pid, cmdline);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do other shells solve those problems? There are several of them that are open source, you could study them.

Comment: _Deleting setpgid will make the mini-shell work again, but it can't be removed since the shell needs to control forked processes in groups._ Exactly _how_ do you want to _control_ processes in groups? That is, what does it do for you? What do you mean by processes [plural] and groups [plural]? And, exactly what is the "freeze up"? What happens when the "shell" is _your_ shell (i.e. you fork and then the child calls its own `main`)?

Comment: @CraigEstey I edited the question because my phrasing was unclear. setpgid was needed because "if the foreground process P forks additional processes P1 and P2, the shell, upon receiving a SIGTSTP from the user, should stop P, P1, and P2. This can be conveniently done if P, P1, P2 are in the same process group whose pgid is the same as P's pid. We can just send SIGTSTP to the entire process group". The shell "freezes" because it is stuck on waitpid. With WUNTRACED enabled, waitpid exits immediately because the forked process is "stopped by a job control signal". In neither case does vi show up

Comment: I'd look at [if you haven't already done so]: `man 2 setsid` and `man credentials` for more information about establishing a new "controlling TTY". Also, I'd pull the source to `bash` and look at what it does. Without that TTY, of course, `vi` is going to have problems. Again, set up your shell so it can `fork` and run itself (either via `main` or `./myshell`). I'd run `gdb` from another window and `attach` to the subshell. Or, more debug `printf` sent to (e.g.) `/tmp/mylog/log.<pid>` Your subshell should have the same issues as another program but is easier to debug.

Comment: In `bash`, look at `jobs.c`. It's somewhat complex, but after doing `setpgid`, it calls `give_terminal_to` which calls `sigprocmask` and `tcsetpgrp`. Other shells may have simpler implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to relinquish control of the tty to the other process group using `tcsetpgrp`, and when the child is done, take back the control of the tty using `tcsetpgrp` again. Note that `tcsetpgrp` sends `SIGTTOU` to its caller [if the calling process belongs to a background process group](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetpgrp.3.html), so `SIGTTOU` and `SIGTTIN` must be blocked.

```
// error handling is omitted for brevity
// these two signal functions can be anywhere before tcsetpgrp
// alternatively, they can be masked during tcsetpgrp
signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
signal(SIGTTIN, SIG_IGN);

if (!builtin_command(argv)) {
    if ((pid = Fork()) == 0) {
        if (execve(argv[0], argv, environ) < 0) {
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            printf("%s: Command not found.\n", argv[0]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    if (!bg) {
        setpgid(pid, 0);
        tcsetpgrp(STDERR_FILENO, pid);
        int status;
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0) {
            unix_error("waitfg: waitpid error");
        }
        tcsetpgrp(STDERR_FILENO, getpgrp());
    } else {
        printf("%d %s", pid, cmdline);
    }
}
```

This is a rather crude implementation. Consult Craig's comments for this question for where to find `bash`'s implementation.